# variable from servlet editing inside JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In have this transfer from a servlet to the jsp. Since the AllPost is a list and I go through it with for, I do not know whether it's a short way close to what I give here.
Meanwhile I solved the issue inside the class, i.e. before the value coming to the servlet & jsp, as below.
So, at this point I do not know whether it makes sense to try further.

Thank you in advance!

```
<c:forEach items="${AllPost}" var ="p">
    <tr>
       <%! int len = Integer.valueOf(${p.detail.length()}); %>
       <%
         if(len<25){
             ${p.detail}.concat("....");
         }
       %>
       <td>${p.detail.substring(0,25)}...</td>
```

The 2nd option code from routine class:

```
ResultSet rs = DB.getPreparedStatement(SQL).executeQuery();
while(rs.next()){
News n = new News(rs.getInt(1),...);
if(Integer.valueOf(rs.getString(1.length())<25){
    String sz = n.getDetail().concat(".........................");
    n.setDetail(sz);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <%! int len = Integer.valueOf(${p.detail.length()}); %>
```

Here you're mixing EL and scriptlets, it's not possible to use both. Not only that, you're using JSTL in your code as well, but still resorting to scriptlets? In almost all cases, if you're using JSTL & EL, you don't need to use any scriptlets. Scriptlets is an oldschool way of using JSPs.

Your code for the first option should look something like this (without scriptlets):

```
<c:forEach items="${AllPost}" var ="p">

 <tr>

 <c:if test="${fn:length(p.detail) lt 25}">
 <td>${p.detail}...</td>
 </c:if>

 <c:if test="${fn:length(p.detail) gt 25}">
 <td>${fn:substring(p.detail, 0, 25)}...</td>
 </c:if>

 </tr>

</c:forEach>
```

make sure to include this at the top of the page for jstl functions (if you haven't already)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

Comment: Yes, more mixing than I supposed :). Tank you so much!

Comment: yup, no problem. Hope it helps. Feel free to mark as the answer if it solved your problem.